# Compatibility option problem in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

In IE8 i face a problem to check the site in compatibility mode for few sites and for few sites I can see the compatibility mode can someone help me out for the same to see the compatibility mode button

Answer (score 2):

Check the following explanation from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/02/16/just-the-facts-recap-of-compatibility-view.aspx):

> Sometimes the Compatibility View
>   button isn’t displayed. The button is
>   located on the address bar next to the
>   ‘stop’ and ‘refresh’ buttons. There
>   are a few cases where there’s no
>   action for a user take and, thus, the
>   Compatibility View button will not
>   show:
>
> - If you're viewing an
>     internal-to-Internet Explorer page
>     (such as about:InPrivate)
> - If you're viewing a page that has
>     declared it's "ready" for Internet
>     Explorer 8 through use of the
>     versioning  tag / HTTP header
>     (it doesn’t matter if this tag
>     triggers Quirks, IE7 Standards, or IE8
>     Standards, the button won’t be
>     displayed)
> - If you're viewing an intranet page and
>     you have the ‘Display intranet sites
>     in Compatibility View’ checkbox
>     selected
> - If you're viewing any webpage and you
>     have the ‘Display all websites in
>     Compatibility View’ checkbox selected
> - If you're viewing a webpage that is
>     included on the Microsoft-supplied
>     compatibility view updates list and
>     you have the ‘Include updated website
>     lists from Microsoft’ checkbox
>     selected
> - If you've toggled either the ‘Document
>     Mode’ or ‘Browser Mode’ settings via
>     the Developer Toolbar

Comment: If a sites does not display the icon it means it's compatible, so does not need the Compatibility Mode.